# Javascript SessionStorage Checking Before Running a Function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I'm calling. Called getStatus(). But this function requires there to be a defined SessionStorage variable that could be present. If the variable is present then I want to go ahead and execute the getJob() function. If it's not present I want to try to define the SessionStorage variable and then execute the getJob() function.

Like this:

```
function getStatus()
  {
    if (sessionGet("jwt") != null)
    {
        getJob(document.getElementById('job').value, document.getElementById('id').value);
    }
    else
    { 
        var myValue = '{{ myValue }}';
        console.log("Token is missing, acquiring another one!");
        var nextToken = setTimeout(function(){ getSessionToken(myValue); }, 5000);
        console.log("Reissued token issued is");
        console.log(nextToken);
        getJob(document.getElementById('job').value, document.getElementById('id').value);
   }
  }
```

And here is the function that reads the SessionStorage variable:

```
function sessionGet(key) {
  let stringValue = window.sessionStorage.getItem(key)
    if (stringValue !== null) {
      let value = JSON.parse(stringValue)
        let expirationDate = new Date(value.expirationDate)
        if (expirationDate > new Date()) {
          return value.value
        } else {
          window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key)
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

When I look at the Chrome console I see the SessionStorage variable being written, but the getJob() function that reads the variable doesn't see it. If I retry then the getJob() function is able to read it. My thought is that the getJob() function is firing before the variable has been written. That's why I tried the setTimeout() in there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does the expirationDate value look like?

Comment: Here is a copy/paste of one of the SessionStorage variables. I know this works overall. Just when it's missing the refresh hits after the getJob() method has already fired...{,…}
expirationDate
:
"2018-03-01T23:36:55.088Z"
value
:
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InNob3BpZnkiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTk5NDcyMzUsImV4cCI6MTUyMDAzMzYzNSwiaWF0IjoxNTE5OTQ3MjM1fQ.U7ydF4gUBiRzFMC1tkUj0LFlrIDX-CSL1Yx2pCcGR5Y

Comment: can you add the the code for `getSessionToken`? is it doing a request?

Comment: It’s more convoluted but it creates a special token and store the value in the sessionstorage variable. But it works. Like I said I can see the variable gets created and assigned in sessionstorage. It just happens a bit after i’ve already called the getJob() function.

Comment: shouldn't you then call the `getJob` function with `setTimeout`?

Comment: Ahh! I'll try that and see how it works. Makes sense, seeing that's the one that needs to wait on the SessionStorage variable to be created and written. Will update this thread as to the outcome!

Answer (score 0):

As ztadic91 pointed out, I needed to wrap the setTimeout around the getJob() function call, since it needed to wait for the SessionStorage variable to be created. After doing that things tested out fine. Appreciate the quick assist!